# Want audacious to be on top of screen

Tags: unity, compiz, fullscreen

I am using double-screen setup and on one screen I have opened terminal in fullscreen and on other screen web-browser and audacious.

I want to have small audacious windows always on top on first screen but here is problem.

If I focus on terminal(which is fullscreen) and then go back to browser, then browser covers audacious(which should be on top).

P.S.- I undestand that fullscreen window should be over always-on-top window(and it's ok). But when focusing from fullscreen to normal window I want to have audacious on top.

How can I force always-on-top to stay after focusing out of fullscreen mode?

In other Words: I would like to have fullscreen windows first, then those which are always-on-top, and then the rest. Regardless of focus.

Answer (score -1):

At least version 4.1 of the software has already the feature builted in.
Go to view > Always on top (ctrl+O).
[http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/audacious.1.html](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/audacious.1.html)

Comment: The man page that you link to shows `Shift + Control + o     Display Add Files dialog`, not always on top

Comment: The ManPage shows `Ctrl+o` to "Display Open Files dialog" and `Shift+Ctrl+o` to "Display Add Files dialog".